# How to convert a list of numbers into a list of exponents?

Tags: python-3.x

so as part of my program i download a list of numbers from a datatset eg [24, 20, 30] but i need to convert them into the form [10^24, 10^20, 10^30] to then run the rest of my program, is there an easy way to do this?

The list will be a different length every time depending on how much i download from the dataset.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1):

Given a generic list, for example lis = [24,20,30] this code is what you need:

```
lis2 = [10**i for i in lis]
```

now lis2 contains [10^24,10^20,10^30]